# Library to view Word files in .Net

Tags: windows, library, .net, office

What libraries are available to open and *graphically edit* .docx files? I need to present forms provided as word files, show them to the user and let them fill in the fields, and then print it.

I've been able to track down Infragistics XamRichTextEditor, which is okay but does not export to PDF / XPS for printing, and also seem quite buggy from my trials.

The other option is Microsoft's interop services, the problem is not all clients have an up-to-date version of Word installed to use it.

Are there any other software libraries available? Most I've found are only for editing files programmatically (Aspose, Gembox etc.). Cost is not a huge concern as long as it's not more than 10.000-15.000$ for the license.

Comment: OpenOffice might have a .NET api, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390006/openoffice-and-net. Of course, users would need to install it, but at least it's free.

Comment: I use [openxml](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5124) for dealing with data in docx files. However, its not the best fit for user editing, much like the examples you give.

Comment: A great one is [NOV RTF](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-rich-text-editor-control-overview.aspx), it reads docx file, let's you edit the file and as if you are editing it in word and exports to PDF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I settled for [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/), which have an excellent word editing component for WPF, which measures up very well to the competition, with fixed layout support, printing, export/import of dozens of format. It's not perfect but much, much better than te competition I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [LEADTOOLS Documents SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-viewer)

The SDK has a Document Viewer, Document Converter, and Document Markup (annotations).

You can download a free 60-day evaluation of the SDK and there is an online demo you can upload your files to test with here:

[LEADTOOLS Interactive Document Viewer Demo](http://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/index.html)

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product